# What are the settings for the EMLG mainnet

Tags: nodeos, mainnet, mainnetlaunch

If I understand correctly, I need a `genesis.json`, and the IP address and port of at least one seed node, to connect `nodeos` to mainnet.

Now mainnet had launched, what are the details to connect to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this guide provided by CryptoLions: https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-MainNet

Answer (score 0):

I found a list of seed nodes at https://eosnodes.privex.io, along with a handy `genesis.json`:

```
{
  "initial_timestamp": "2018-06-08T08:08:08.888",
  "initial_key": "EOS7EarnUhcyYqmdnPon8rm7mBCTnBoot6o7fE2WzjvEX2TdggbL3",
  "initial_configuration": {
    "max_block_net_usage": 1048576,
    "target_block_net_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_net_usage": 524288,
    "base_per_transaction_net_usage": 12,
    "net_usage_leeway": 500,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_num": 20,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_den": 100,
    "max_block_cpu_usage": 200000,
    "target_block_cpu_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_cpu_usage": 150000,
    "min_transaction_cpu_usage": 100,
    "max_transaction_lifetime": 3600,
    "deferred_trx_expiration_window": 600,
    "max_transaction_delay": 3888000,
    "max_inline_action_size": 4096,
    "max_inline_action_depth": 4,
    "max_authority_depth": 6
  }
}
```